# Should I virtualliy split a multi-port NIC for various virtual machines in Hyper-V?

Tags: hyper-v, nic

I have a NIC with 4 ports running on Hyper-V. I would be running two virtual machines one would be a WS2012R2 (DC, DNS, DHCP, FS, RRAS, etc.) and a W7 (basically used with one application that needs high storage I/O).

Would it be wise to split each port of the NIC to just ONE virtual machine at a time?

Comment: `Would it be wise to split each port of the NIC to just ONE virtual machine at a time?` - No. Why would it be? Do you intend to build your host machine with a physical NIC for every VM? Create a virtual switch with one NIC and assign your virtual machines to the virtual switch.

Comment: Having so little virtual machines, it would be better to use all the ports to, like @Daniel mentioned, stop bandwidth from having to be split between virtual machines. My plan was to dedicate 3 NICs: 1 for Hyper-V Core (if neccesary, I dont mind spliting this one with WS2012R2), 1 for WS2012R2, and another for W7. I would still have one NIC port free...

Comment: Nobody does this or they do it very rarely. Dedicating a physical NIC to each VM kind of defeats the purpose of virtualization. What happens when you have ten virtual machines? Or twenty? Just because you can do this because you only have two virtual machines doesn't mean you should do it.

Comment: I mentioned we are NEVER going to have that many VMs. You ignore the point of what was said that splitting each port of the NIC would reduce the bandwidth load on one port. Is there a reason why  I SHOULDN'T? split each port for each VM? Is there a issue?

Comment: I didn't ignore that point. I made the point that nobody does this. Is there a reason you shouldn't split them? Yes, it seems like a foolish and shortsighted use of the physical resources. But don't take my word for it. Run some tests and see for yourself what the utilization is with both virtual machines using the same physical NIC and see if there's any "contention". I'm not saying that this is never done, but I am saying that it's rarely done and only in edge cases. Your intended reason for doing it doesn't stand up to the reasonability check, nor would it be considered "best practice".

Comment: Why is it a foolish or shortsighted use of physical resources? What would you dedicate the rest of those ports? Load balancing? Failover? Those are great two, I can still dedicate that leftover port I have for that! If I brought it up, do you really think it is something rare? I would have read it somewhere, right?

Comment: Just because the ports are available doesn't mean you have to use them. I have 3 Hyper-V hosts, each with a 4 port NIC. 3 NIC's are used and one is unused. I don't feel compelled to find a use for the 4th NIC. If I need it in the future, it'll be there.

Comment: You completely blew over my question of "Why is it a foolish or shortsighted use of physical resources?" Splitting the ports on the NIC would not give me negative performance and would actually improve performance because you are dedicating one port per virtual machine. Imagine this: 2 tubes, one with pears falling thru them, another with apples falling thru them. If we only had 1 tube, and both apples and pears fell thru the same tube, the basket wouldn't be as full of pears/apples as if we had 2 tubes where only pears/apples go thru, nonstop into two separate baskets.

Comment: If your goal is to separate the apples from the pears then fine, but if you're doing it because you think the combination of apples and pears will overload the tube, then you're wrong.

Answer (score 2):

A better idea is to use the built in NIC teaming.  I would set it up as:

- One NIC for the host OS, so I can access the host even if some of the other networking is broken.
- Two NICs in a team for all the VMs
- One NIC left over, possibly for use in clustering or live migrations if another server ever gets added.

By using teams you get a few advantages:

- Easy to add another VM down the road.  You may not need it now, but one day you might want to test something on a fresh VM or add some new services.
- Less administrative headaches - no need to remember which NIC goes with which VM.
- Redundancy.  You can pull out one of those two cables and everything keeps working.  You can even connect them to separate switches for switch redundancy or to migrate to new network hardware without any downtime.
- Better speeds, since under the right circumstances a single VM can use the bandwidth of both NICs.  This is the big advantage you are looking at, and by pooling the NICs it helps all the VMs get better than single dedicated NIC speeds.  If you really need more speed you could even add the third NIC to the team.

Comment: Right now, one NIC is used for the host. The other 3 are in a team and they are shared with X virtual machines (Right now, that number X is 2)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't split (which then would be done using a bridge to combine everything), the two machines would have to share the bandwidth one port of your NIC provides. Mapping a dedicated port to each VM would provide the full speed available per port for each machine. So yes, I would do that. Although I'm curious if someone knows of downsides doing it that way.